# knex.js - simpler way to update data

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I want to update a table called client. The following code works for valid id's but for invalid ones it just hangs without calling the catch function.

```
knex('client').where('id',id).update({
        name:req.body.name
        }).then(function(numberOfUpdatedRows) {
            if(numberOfUpdatedRows) {
                res.json(success);
                return;
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.status('500');
            res.json(err);
            return;         
        }); 
});
```

I solved the problem like this :

```
knex('client').where('id',id).select('id').then(function(id){
        if(id) {
            //update 
        }else {
            //failed
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("select id do not exist");
        res.send("do not exist");
    });
```

For this case also, for invalid ids knex is not calling the catch function but instead of hanging up returns an empty value for the id, which i use for error checking.
I am a beginner and am sure am there is a better way to doing this.
Could some one please suggest a better way ?
Also, I could not find much in the [knex documentation](http://knexjs.org/) about how knex handles error cases like this. So where can I find that information, so I can solve them by myself in the future. Thanks.

Comment: validate your data first.

Comment: Check out my solution. @FazalRasel no validation is needed.

Answer (score 4):

A good example for you would be this

```
db("table")
.update({deleted_at: "now()"})
.where("column", "value");
```

if you want more information look this: https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#update

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code execution that is why the `catch` method is not executed. A neat way to catch not found errors on update is like this

```
const {name} = req.body;
knex("client")
  .update({name})
  .where({id})
.then(rows => {
  // the argument here as you stated
  // describes the number of rows updated
  // therefore if no row found no row will be updated
  if (!rows){
    return res.status(404).json({success:false});
  }
  return res.json({success:true});
})
.catch( e => res.status(500).json(e));
```

or if you like one lines

```
const {name} = req.body;
knex("client")
  .update({name})
  .where({id})
  .then(u => res.status(!!u?200:404).json({success:!!u}))
  .catch(e => res.status(500).json(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
knex
  .select('id')
  .from('client')
  .where('id', id)
  .then(([row]) => {
    if (!row) {
      console.log("select id do not exist")
      return res.send("do not exist")
    }
    return knex('client')
      .update('name', req.body.name)
      .where('id', row.id)
  });
```

if I already know the row may not exist, i'll treat this a logic error which should be handled by code.

Answer (score 1):

use knex like this

```
const {id,name} = req.body;
    const subQuery = knex('client').select('id').where({id})
    subQuery.then(response=>{
    if(response.length>0){
        subQuery.update({name})
        .then(resp=>{
            res.json('update done')
        })
        .catch(err=>{res.json(err)})
    }
    else{
        res.json('update failed')
     }
})
.catch(err=>{res.json(err)})
```